# Custom page with user selected nodes

Tags: 7, views

I want to allow my users to print a pdf with the nodes they want.
I thought to create a view and use the Print module to generate the pdf, but I don't know how to let them choose the nodes.
I tried with Panels, but it's a bit complicated for standard user.
I thought to use some cck field to manage this, but since the custom page is per user, this is not possible.
Did anybody face the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module to allow users to select nodes. Flag integrates nicely with Views, so you can create a view of nodes flagged by the current user.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue), or flag, and views.

If you use nodequeue, take a look at (for printing) : http://drupal.org/node/348682